# How to manually build a universal ruby on Mac OS X? How about with rvm?

Tags: ruby, macos, build, rvm, universal-binary

I got the ruby sources from the [official git mirror](http://github.com/ruby/ruby), then checked out the `ruby_1_9_2` branch.

```
git clone http://github.com/ruby/ruby.git
git checkout ruby_1_9_2
```

So, for now, I want to compile 1.9.2-head. But as you'll see later I'm hoping for a solution that works for 1.8 too.

The standard way to compile this is:

```
autoconf
./configure
make
make install
```

That works, but it yields me a x86_64-only build:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-06-14 revision 28321) [x86_64-darwin10.3.0]
```

I don't care about PPC, obviously, since I'm on 10.6, but I want to have both i386 and x86_64, because [some things](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/rb-appscript-discuss/2010-May/000343.html) need to be done in 32-bit.

#### So, what I want to know:

1. the magic chants to build a fat binary with both i386 and x86_64 archs.
2. I would also be interested in doing the same with my [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) ruby versions.

#### Probably unecessary system information:

```
$ system_profiler -detailLevel mini SPSoftwareDataType | ack '^ {6}' | head -3
      System Version: Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 10.4.0
      64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No

$ uname -a
Darwin meaningless.local 10.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--with-arch` option to `./configure`:

```
$ ./configure --with-arch=x86_64,i386
```

`--with-arch` takes a comma-separated list of architectures for which Ruby should be built.

---

#### added by kch:

Output after a successful build:

```
$ file ruby
ruby: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
ruby (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
ruby (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386

$ arch -i386 ./ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-06-29 revision 28468) [universal.i386-darwin10.4.0]

$ arch -x86_64 ./ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-06-29 revision 28468) [universal.x86_64-darwin10.4.0]

$ ./ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-06-29 revision 28468) [universal.x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

Comment: No problem, I was about to update it with the relevant output myself.

Comment: @zengr Post a new question with your problem, will try to help.

Comment: @kch Thanks, the question is posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197686/install-ruby-1-9-2-on-mac-osx-10-6-with-32bit-version

Answer (score 1):

As for RVM, [it says you can't have fat binaries](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/os/darwin/), but that's not true as of [this commit](http://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/4bcb64be231ee40201f995a5d090de05d40981a6) which incorporates [my patch](http://github.com/kch/rvm/compare/configure-comma-fix).

Using the latest rvm you can install `ruby-1.9.2-head` using the same configure flag as in the manual build:

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.2-head -C --with-arch=x86_64,i386
```

---

#### Proof that it's supposedly working:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2-head
info: Using ruby 1.9.2 head

$ file `which ruby` | perl -pe 's|^.*/||'
ruby: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
ruby (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
ruby (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
```

Comment: Just FYI, doesn't work work for 1.8.7-p352, simple comparison of configure.in files showed that multi-arch support part present in 1.9.2 is missing in 1.8.7.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for ruby-2.0.0; it fails for me with `Error running '__rvm_make -j 1'`, tied to `ld: unknown option: -fstack-protector` in the log.