# Install Ruby 1.9.2 on Mac OSX 10.6 with 32bit version

Tags: ruby, macos, 32-bit

I have started with Ruby app development and I see that there are many Ruby Gems which don't work on 64bit (which I have installed right now). Their moderators have suggested to use 32bit build for Snow Leopard(10.6).

I went to Ruby's website, but didn't find a separate installer for Ruby 1.9.2 for 32bit 10.6

So, how do I fix it? Will I have to remove my existing Ruby 1.9.2 and install the 32bit version?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

[Problem](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/212699)
This is what the **moderators** told me:

> You may be a bit stuck for getting
>   wxRuby working with the system ruby
>   provided in 10.6. Apple has made
>   things difficult by moving to 64-bit
>   architecture. I'm using 10.6 and for
>   wxRuby applications I'm using my own
>   32-bit build of Ruby 1.9.1. This works
>   just fine with the gems that are
>   downloadable from Rubyforge.

Comment: I think you will have to configure your C compiler to use a 32-bit `long` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Problems compiling native gems under Snow Leopard + RVM](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/8d385835387c5ed7?hl=en)

and the [gist](http://gist.github.com/456916)

Answer (score 1):

First, install Ruby Version Manager

- https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Then, you can install any number of interpreters for Ruby. to install 1.9.2

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

Comment: so, 1.9.2-head means 1.9.2. for mac 10.6, 32bit version? Where do I specify the 64/32bit?

Comment: more info is available at the rvm home page, but I believe 1.9.2-head is the 32 bit version.If you want something else you can specify compiler flags and specific release tags, etc. http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/installing/ Wayne (the head contributor) is almost always on the irc channel to answer questions.

Comment: That still installs the 64bit version of Ruby by default and they have no mailing list. I am trying it on irc